Unusually high Uassigned traffic on my sites
I have 3 sites that use Google Analytics to monitor incoming traffic that are experiencing unusually hight Unassigned traffic.
I tried cheking if the problem was with my CMP blocking any cookie/script or denying the wrong consent types but this seems not the be case as other sites with the same CMP seem to work properly with almost no Unassigned traffic. I also tried debugging using Google Tag Asssistant but consent is set before any tag tries to get user data and page_view event is sent with Session ID, Page Location and Client ID. I can provide sceenshots or other info if needed.

We also had higher bot traffic in the last month. Digging into the logs we found that it was caused by AI bots. Especially Anthropic’s ClaudeBot, supported by Amazon, was very aggressive. We now block all AI bots with all means at our disposal. After all, these bots are not working for our benefit, it is basically theft on a large scale.

I don't know why you even looked at CMP. How could it possibly influence channel attribution?
Inspect the UTM params of the incoming traffic. Use the GA4 data for it. Find the UTM parameters with the source that doesn't get bucketed in any of the existing sources. That will land in the unassigned land.

I checked the CMP because we noticed that when we disabled the plugin the unassigned traffic decreased so we tought it could be that the CMP was blocking some cookie used by google to gather user informations. In partucular the unassigned traffic gets even worse when we lauch paid campaigns so we tought it was some problem related to the Conversion Linker but we dropped the hypothesis because the biggest toll was on the organic search traffic. Anyway i'll check the UTM parameters and i'll update the question ASAP, Thank you for your answer.

I would also suggest checking the referrer, especially for the misassigned organic traffic, but I don't know what it should be to get to unassigned. It should probably be so bad that GA's url parser wouldn't be able to recognize it as a url.

It might be helpful to compare the configurations between the sites that are working correctly and the one with the high unassigned traffic. Sometimes, small discrepancies in how tags or triggers are set up can cause unexpected issues. Also, double-check whether there are any recent updates or changes to the analytics or tag management setup that might have been overlooked. If you have access to server logs, review them for any unusual activity or errors that might explain the discrepancy in traffic data.
